# How to lookup the value from one php associative array in another one without looping?

Tags: php, associative-array, lookup

I have two PHP associative arrays that store user info and transactions respectively. They have values in common in one "column" (user email address, let's not get into whether that's a valid unique identifier).

I am looping through the first array to build up an HTML table, and I want to display values from the 2nd array whenever there is a match on that key they have in common, i.e. there is transaction information to be displayed for the current email address.

I would rather avoid writing complex JOIN MYSQL statements to build up one bigger array from my source data (edit: if there's an easier way to meet the same goal in PHP).

I have searched high and low (SO and other forums, PHP doc) but everything I've seen so far involves (nested) looping, which strikes me as inefficient, the more so as you have more records. Is there something somewhat like Excel's VLOOKUP native to PHP that I am missing?

Comment: even if you don't do the loop yourself, the function will be - so writing a better db query would be a far better idea

Comment: Can you show some sample code?  It just sounds like you want to have an multiple indexing levels, e.g., x[y['abc']], but I can't be sure.  Also agree with previous comment- use the db to effect joins.

Comment: I'm bad at PHP, but I'm terrible at MySQL, hence my search for PHP native functions to do the job. in_array does that sort of lookup, but it's not returning the actual value.

Answer (score 0):

1. You've got your problem right out of nowhere. There is not a slightest problem with loops over data of the display size. It's okay to leave it as is.
2. Your "I would rather avoid a proper solution, so find me another" sounds a bit arrogant to me.
3. Anyway, there is a simple "solution" you're looking for - you can use email as a key for the second array when forming it.